# Programatically get the path for a LocalDb database using EF 6

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have an EF 6 project targeting LocalDb where the connection string only specifies the initial catalog name and not the file path.

On my machine the location is `%USERDIRECTORY%\Database.mdf` but I believe this applies to new versions of LocalDb only.

Is there a way to programatically find out where EF creates this file irrespective of the LocalDb version? Please note I am NOT specifying the `AttachDBFilename` parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to run a [raw database query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592907.aspx) like this:

```sql
SELECT physical_name 
FROM sys.database_files 
WHERE [type] = 0
```